# Symfony2 - 2.6 file uploads

Tags: symfony, file-upload

I'm having a problem with file uploads on 2.6, which worked fine on the previous versions. I can't figure out what the problem is, there is no error and when I dump the post object I see a file name there but there is no file in the images folder.

My images folder is in myproject/web/images.

Using SonataAdmin to upload the file and again no errors there.

**Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong or what's changed?**

**Edit:** After perusing through the folders I noticed it created another web/images folder in /var/www/html.

Any idea how correct this? My project folder is in /var/www/html/myproject.

Tried adding 2 more /../../ but got an error: `Unable to create the "/var/www/html/myproject/src/AppBundle/Entity/../../../../../../web/images/" directory`. And removed 2 /../../ and still nothing.

Calling the file in twig with the following:

```
{% for photo in photos %}
    <a href="{{ asset(['images/', photo.image]|join) }}">
        <img src="{{ asset(['images/', photo.image]|join) }}" width="400" height="600" alt=""/>
    </a>
{% endfor %}
```

Post entity

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="file", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $image;

public $file;


/**
 * Set image
 *
 * @param string $image
 * @return Post
 */
public function setImage($image)
{
    $this->image = $image;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get image
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getImage()
{
    return $this->image;
}

public function getUploadDir()
{
    return 'images/';
}

public function getUploadRootDir()
{
    return __DIR__ . '/../../../../web/' . $this->getUploadDir();
}

public function getWebPath()
{
    return null === $this->image ? null : $this->getUploadDir() . '/' . $this->image;
}

public function getAbsolutePath()
{
    return null === $this->image ? null : $this->getUploadRootDir() . '/' . $this->image;
}

/**
 * @ORM\PrePersist()
 * @ORM\PreUpdate()
 */
public function preUpload()
{
    if (null !== $this->file) {
        $this->image = uniqid() . '.' . $this->file->guessExtension();
    }
}

/**
 * @ORM\PostPersist()
 * @ORM\PostUpdate()
 */
public function upload()
{
    if (null === $this->file) {
        return;
    }

    // If there is an error when moving the file, an exception will
    // be automatically thrown by move(). This will properly prevent
    // the entity from being persisted to the database on error
    $this->file->move($this->getUploadRootDir(), $this->image);

    $this->file = null;
}

/**
 * @ORM\PostRemove()
 */
public function removeUpload()
{
    if ($file = $this->getAbsolutePath()) {
        unlink($file);
    }
}
```

Comment: myproject/web/images is writeable? what are the permission you have given to it?

Comment: Yes. Changed the owner to www-data:www-data and permission is 775.

Comment: Can you try this and let us know if its working
public function getUploadDir()
{
    return 'images'; //remove trailing slash(/)
}

Comment: Yes sir, have tried this as well, and still nothing.

Comment: It's still upload the files to the wrong directory. `/var/www/html/web/images` instead of `/var/www/html/myproject/web/images`.

Comment: Can you give us your entity path?

Comment: The entity is in `var/www/html/myproject/src/AppBundle/Entity/Post.php`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71860/discussion-between-ashish-awasthi-and-purple-dot).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Entity Path is:

```
var/www/html/myproject/src/AppBundle/Entity/Post.php
```

and your `getUploadRootDir` method:

```
public function getUploadRootDir()
{
    return __DIR__ . '/../../../../web/' . $this->getUploadDir();
}
```

Which will go back four times cause there are 4(../) which is taking you to out of your source directory.

use this to resolve this error:

```
public function getUploadRootDir()
{
    return __DIR__ . '/../../../web/' . $this->getUploadDir(); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir for your patience and help. Much obliged.

Answer (score 0):

Just Change your entity with this.

Instead of

```
public function getUploadDir()
{
    return 'images/';
}
```

Replace This

```
public function getUploadDir()
{
    return '/images';
}
```

Comment: Tried this, and no it doesn't work. And even tried keeping/removing the trailing slash on web `'/../../../../web'` and still nothing. It still uploads to `var/www/html/web/images`.

Comment: in which dir you want to upload your file in images? right?

Comment: if yes then just create one more dir in web Upload and replace....   public function getUploadDir()
{
    return 'Upload/images';
}